# How to define links for OAS3 using Swashbuckle?

Tags: asp.net-core, openapi, swashbuckle

I have noticed that in the Swagger UI v3 and in OAS3 we now have support for something called "[links](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/links/)"

But I cant really figure out if its possible to use this feature with Swashbuckle, and if it is.. then how? Been searching the net and haven't found anything regarding this..

Anyone been able to use links with Swashbuckle?

Comment: Also interested in finding out how to implement this

Answer (score 2):

You can use an OperationFilter. Create a class that implements IOperationFilter

```
public class MyLinkFilter : IOperationFilter 
{
```

into it select the response for which you want to add Links.

```
public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    var responses = operation.Responses;
    var response = responses.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Key == "200").Value;
```

then update the Links property

```
response.Links = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiLink>
{
    { 
        "YourKey"
        ,new OpenApiLink {
            OperationId = "YourOperationId",
            Description = ".............",
            Parameters = new Dictionary<string, RuntimeExpressionAnyWrapper>
            {
                {
                    "yourParam", new RuntimeExpressionAnyWrapper
                    {
                        Any = new OpenApiString("$request.path.number")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Register your OperationFilter into startup.cs

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
  {
     options.OperationFilter<MyLinkFilter>();
  });
```

[OpenAPI, Response](https://swagger.io/specification/#response-object)

[OpenAPI, Link](https://swagger.io/specification/#link-object)

Finally, you'll have to implement a mechanism to apply the links to the good Action in your controller.